# How to use findstr when my regex needs a space in it

Tags: svn, batch-file

I'm trying to write a `findstr` regex that will find local and remote modified files using subversion.
Given the example output below I'd like to match those lines having an 'M' as the first or second characters. There will be others also, but this is my starting point.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\code>svn status --show-updates .
X                    Core
        *     4069   D3_Version.m
Status against revision:   4184

Performing status on external item at 'Core'
M             4184   Core\IE_Unexport_Signals.m
X                    Core\2010
 M            4184   Core\images
 M            4184   Core
Status against revision:   4184

Performing status on external item at 'Core\2010'
Status against revision:   4184
```

My regex looks like: `svn status --show-updates . |findstr "^[M]"` which gives:
    M             4184   IECore\IE_Unexport_Signals.m

This only picks us the M in the first column. Modifying to also pick up the second column results in no output: `svn status --show-updates . |findstr "^[ M][ M]"`
This seems to be due to the space in the character class. Reading the docs I should use `/C:` to interpret the space as literal but this takes *all* characters as literals and therefore the regex won't work.
Also escaping the space with "\ " doesn't work.

How can I match those lines having an 'M' as the first or second characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command seems to do the trick:

```
svn status --show-updates . |findstr /r "^M ^.M"
```

It uses two regular expressions separated by a space.

Comment: That is an interesting work around. Using it I've extended the regex to include the other patterns I'm interested in [http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html] and come up with `svn st -u |findstr /r "^[ADMRCXI?!~] ^.[MC] ^..L ^...\+ ^....S ^.....[KOTB] ^......\*"`. It's not pretty but should do the job without any false positives. Ideally I'd like a 'cleaner' answer though...